# Style root element using css file, but not working

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack

I have the entry component in reactjs:

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from "./js/components/App.js"
import './index.css';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I am trying to style in the root element inside of my css file, index.css:

```
  #root {

    background-color: brown;
    height:100vh;
    width:100vh;
  }
```

The background though is not brown. When looking at the styling the browser renders I cannot see any of these attributes being applied to the root element.

This is my webpack config:

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['css-loader'],
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html",
      filename: "./index.html"
    })
  ]
};
```

It is as if it is not loading the index.css file at all.

Comment: you are applying background color twice.

Comment: sorry that was a type while I was debugging. Removed it now

Answer (score 0):

You cannot style the `#root` of your app. Just style the `className` of `<App />` component, for example:

```
const App = () => (
  <div className="app>
  // ...
  </div>
)
```

css file:

```
.app {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-color: brown;
  height:100vh;
  width:100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using webpack,  i think you have to specify your entry points of your css/js files like this...

```
entry: [
        "./src/js/index.js",
        "./src/sass/style.scss",
    ],
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets/js')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
/* you code here */
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

#### soln-workaround 1

- use **Javascript**
- vv

  ```
  const root = document.getElementById('root') as HTMLDivElement;
  root.style.cssText = "height: 100%;       border: 1px solid green;";
  ```

#### soln-workaround 2

- **put the `<style>` directly in the html**, instead of inside the css.
- vv

  ```html
  <style>
    #root {
      height: 100%;
      border: 1px solid green;
    }
  </style>
  ```

---

#### misc

- *Have the same problem. & Idk how others did it. & I dont think my post is a good solution.*
- *It needs to be on the root, not on another `<div>` wraps the App, cuz I need to get `height: 100%` working.*
- the use of `:root` doesnt work
- the use of `.App` doesnt work
- related post

  > [Style root element using css file, but not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56202718/style-root-element-using-css-file-but-not-working) (this post)
  >
  > [CSS 100% height not working in React app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46769706/css-100-height-not-working-in-react-app) (Idk **why** ppl in this post seems **have no issue**...)
  >
  > [Style background color of root React Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52856010/style-background-color-of-root-react-javascript) (**source** of the soln-workaround)